# Flutter HTTP Request Called Multiple Times On App Load

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a flutter project that makes an http request to gather json of inventory items then render it on screen in a list view. When a user scrolls to the bottom it then loads more inventory by triggering another http call. However my initial HTTP call is being called multiple times. And I am not sure how to handle that.

The result I get is my finish print statement just triggers continuously. At first I thought I had it working because it does load the inventory to my list view. But then I noticed It just keeps loading the same data into my list view non stop. When I added that finish print statement it became clear that it is actually continuously making that http call non stop.

Id like to have it only make the call once, then make a new call again when the user scrolls to bottom.

Any tips will help thank you.

Here is my code.

Network Code

```
Future <List <dynamic>> fetchInventory() async{
dynamic response = await http.get('https:somelink.com',
  headers: {'x-api-key': 'mykey'},);

var inventory = List<dynamic>();

//if 200 response is given then set inventory var to inventoryJson value from the http call
if (response.statusCode == 200){
  dynamic inventoryJson = jsonDecode(response.body);
  inventory = inventoryJson['page'];
  print('finish');
}
//Inventory is returned
    return inventory;
  }
}
```

Here is my how I am using that code in my main file

```
class _WelcomeScreenState extends State<WelcomeScreen> {

  //Create Network Helper Obj
  NetworkHelper networkHelper = NetworkHelper();
  //invenrtory List is set to empty
  var inventory = [];
  var _controller = ScrollController();
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // set up listener here
    _controller.addListener(() {
      if (_controller.position.pixels == _controller.position.maxScrollExtent) {
        // Perform your task
        //This method fetches the data from the fetchInventory method
        print('at bottom');
        networkHelper.fetchInventory().then((value) {

          //This set state will set the value returned from fetchInventory method to the local inventory List
          setState(() {
            this.inventory = value;
          });
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //Used to format currency shown in view
    var currencyFormat = NumberFormat('##,###.00', 'en_US');

    //This method fetches the data from the fetchInventory method


        networkHelper.fetchInventory().then((value){
          //This set state will set the value returned from fetchInventory method to the local inventory List
          setState(() {
            this.inventory.addAll(value);
          });
        });


    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0.0,
        title: AppBarTitle(),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0, right: 5.0, bottom: 25.0),
        child: ListView.builder(
          controller: _controller,
          itemCount: inventory.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index){
    enter code here
    enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

The responsibility of the build method is to construct a widget tree, and this method may be called repeatedly by the framework whenever it thinks that the screen might have changed and need to be re-rendered. As a result, its important that as little work as possible is done here. Remote calls over the network should be avoided, and implementers should try not to call setState as this will cause the UI rendering to loop.

Listening to the scroll controller as demonstrated is a good way of 'Loading more', what is missing is an initial load of the inventory in the `initState()` method.

So, you should move the call to networkHelper.fetchInventory() from the build method to the scrollcontroller callback (as it adds to the inventory)  and move the existing call to networkHelper.fetchInventory() that initialises the inventory from the scrollcontroller callback to the start of the initState method.